# any idea to use web API which is in Json format in ibm worklight

Tags: json, web-applications, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

Iam working IBM workligth IDE. since i am new to it. i am finding out a way to use WEB Api in that IDE. but i was not sucessful. i even found this link but was not what i expected  http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html. is there any way to use the web api which is in json form in ibm worklight. any suggestions or ideas wolud be great.

here is my web api details

```
Request URI:

  http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v1/search.ashx?q=Chennai&format=json&key=53jjtnrm9d5jucpmxyyhj7vn
```

Request Headers:

```
{
"X-Originating-Ip": "14.140.167.22"
 }


Response Headers

    {
"Age": "0",
"Cache-Control": "public, no-cache=\"Set-Cookie\", max-age=120",
"Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
"Date": "Tue, 17 Sep 2013 08:02:27 GMT",
"Server": "Microsoft-IIS/7.5",
"X-Aspnet-Version": "4.0.30319",
"X-Cache": "MISS",
"X-Mashery-Responder": "prod-j-worker-eu-west-1a-90.mashery.com",
"X-Powered-By": "UKFast Webcelerator",
"Transfer-Encoding": "chunked",
"Connection": "keep-alive"
   }

Response Body:

      {
    "search_api": {
    "result": [{
        "areaName": [{
            "value": "Chennai"
        }],
        "country": [{
            "value": "India"
        }],
        "latitude": "13.083",
        "longitude": "80.283",
        "population": "0",
        "region": [{
            "value": "Tamil Nadu"
        }],
        "weatherUrl": [{
            "value": "http:\/\/www.worldweatheronline.com\/Chennai-weather\/Tamil-Nadu\/IN.aspx"
        }]
    }]
    }
     }
```

Comment: you would write a http adapter, then in your client use the invoke command to call it.

Comment: any examples or pdf's?

Comment: There is an article in my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adapters?

There is a good article on REST/JSON web services with Worklight using HTTP adapters: 
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/using_ibm_worklight_http_adapters_with_rest_json_services7?lang=en

An adapter is added to the Worklight Server, which acts like a proxy for the client (without breaking typical web conventions of "no outside server communications")

Hope this helps